# UnrecognizedPropertyException in Jersey Test Framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jersey-test-framework

I am new to Jersey test framework. I am trying to implement test cases using jersey test framework in my project. I have a REST service whose url will be :

`http://localhost:8080/EzSupportBackend/a/dealerservices/getdealerdetails/FAB/ACZOKuBmtvyni16eMJ3AoSVg_HxL3bh3Lz0WiWNJhXudh9M90LSc8bDHD-Y2JpcbISZcC_DM2PL4yqSsmXUKA65ZmvuoiQ_wotgU1OvA8GGw_yPMwVnXGg==`

I tried to test this service using Jersey with the below code:

```
public class DealerServicesTest extends JerseyTest{
@Override
protected AppDescriptor  configure() {
    return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder().build();
}

@Test
public void testGetDealerDetails() throws JSONException,URISyntaxException {
    WebResource webResource = client().resource("http://localhost:8080/");
    JSONObject json = webResource.path("EzSupportBackend/a/dealerservices/getdealerdetails/FAB/ACZOKuBmtvyni16eMJ3AoSVg_HxL3bh3Lz0WiWNJhXudh9M90LSc8bDHD-Y2JpcbISZcC_DM2PL4yqSsmXUKA65ZmvuoiQ_wotgU1OvA8GGw_yPMwVnXGg==").get(JSONObject.class);

    assertEquals("ONLINE", json.get("companyType"));
    assertEquals("FabFurnish", json.get("companyName"));        
    assertEquals("Gurgoan,Haryana, India", json.get("companyAddress"));
    assertEquals("04222456803", json.get("phoneNumber"));
    assertEquals("ACTIVE", json.get("status"));     
    assertEquals("customerservice@fabfurnish.com", json.get("emailId"));
}
}
```

When i test the service thro Postman (Chrome Extension) , i get a proper response as below:

```
{
  "companyType": "ONLINE",
  "companyName": "FabFurnish",
  "companyAddress": "Gurgoan,Haryana, India",
  "companyLocation": null,
  "longitude": "77.023419",
  "phoneNumber": "04222456803",
  "serviceRating": 0,
  "repairRating": 0,
  "warrantyRating": 0,
  "shopRating": 0,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "createdOn": 1446613095557,
  "updatedOn": 1446613095557,
  "companyId": "FAB",
  "lattitde": "28.47427",
  "emailId": "customerservice@fabfurnish.com",
  "createdby": null,
  "updatedby": null
}
```

But thro this test i get the below exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException:     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "companyType" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@45b4c3a9; line: 1, column: 17] (through reference chain: org.json.JSONObject["companyType"])
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:563)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:191)
    at com.vs.mhs.ezsupport.services.DealerServicesTest.testGetDealerDetails(DealerServicesTest.java:27)
```

Anyone can help me figure out why??

EDIT:
My code looks like below:

```
@PermitAll
@GET
@Path("/getdealerdetails/{companyId}/{token_id}")
public Response getDealerDetails(@PathParam("companyId") String companyId, @Context SecurityContext userContext, @Context HttpServletRequest request){
    boolean isUserAuthorised = isUserAuthenticated(userContext);
    DealerDetails dealer = null;
    DealerDetailsView getDealerView = null;
    if(isUserAuthorised){
        EntityManager em = (EntityManager) request.getAttribute(FilterConstants.ENTITYMANAGER);
        DealerDetailsBDL dealerbdl = new DealerDetailsBDL(em);
        dealer = dealerbdl.getDealerDetails(companyId);
        getDealerView = new DealerDetailsView(dealer);
    }
    return Response.ok(getDealerView).build();          
}
```

DealerDetailsView is a class with private variables for the properties i ve listed below and getters and setters:

```
private String companyid;
private String companyType;
private String companyName;
private String companyAddress;
private String companyLocation;
private String lattitude;
private String longitude;
private String phoneNumber;
private String emailid;
private int serviceRating;
private int repairRating;
private int warrantyRating;
private int shopRating;
private String status;
```

Comment: It seems that `companyType` is not known at your POJO. Can you show your mapping class for this json.

Comment: Patrick, i ve edited the question to show the mapping class- DealerDetailsView. is this what u asked for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson is the JSON provider, and Jackson generally works with model POJOs, which `JSONObject` is not. Jackson is looking for a `companyType` property in `JSONObject`, which it doesn't have. That's why you are getting the exception. If you don't have a POJO specifically for that JSON, then just get it as a String, and create the `JSONObject` with that string

```
String jsonString = webResource...get(String.class);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

---

#### UPDATE

A POJO for Jackson is just a class that maps the JSON fields to class properties (that follow JavaBean namming convention). For example for these two JSON fields

```
"companyType": "ONLINE",
"companyName": "FabFurnish"
```

You can have a class like

```
public class CompanyInfo {
    private String companyType;
    private String companyName;

    public CompanyInfo() {}

    public String getCompanyInfo() { return companyInfo; }
    public void setCompanyInfo(String info) { this.companyInfo = info; }
    
    public String getCompanyType() { return companyType; }
    public void setCompanyType(String type) { this.companyType = type; }
}
```

To match the JSON field with the Java property, the property (getter/setter) should be prefixed with `get/set` and the exact name of the field, with the first letter capitalized, as shown above. So just complete the POJO with all the other JSON fields, and the serialization should work with `CompanyInfo`.

Comment: This worked, i am getting as a string. Thank you @peeskillet. Can you please tell me how do i return a pojo for that JSON. My code looks like below:

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet. In this case, then i am sending a POJO called DealerDetailsView. Please see my edit in my question for the code. So y is  it not considering my response as POJO and as String?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The  response comes in a raw JSON, which can be retrieved as a raw string. If you want to get it as a POJO, then use `get(CompanyInfo.class)` or `get(DealerDetailsView.class)`.

Comment: Got u... Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I just have another doubt. What if i am returning an array of CompanyInfo class? How do u get it in my test class?

Comment: `get(new GenericType<List<CompanyInfo>>(){})` will return a `List<CompanyInfo>`

Comment: I am geting a list of DealerDetailsView object as          `List<DealerDetailsView> dealerDetailsList = webResource.path("....").get(new GenericType<List<DealerDetailsView>>(){});` and i am getting         `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.vs.mhs.view.DealerDetailsView`

Comment: Look at the raw JSON. Is it an actual JSON array ( `[ {..}, {..} ]` )?

Comment: If i put like `List<DealerDetailsView> dealerDetailsList = webResource.path(path).get(ArrayList.class)`,   i am getting the array, but getting exception when i try to iterate thro the arraylist using for(DealerDetailsView dd : dealerDetailslist){} `java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.vs.mhs.view.DealerDetailsView`

Comment: The arraylist is like [{...},{...}...]